# what is the radius of convergence of power series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

given a power series S = $\sum (1+n+2^{n}) x^{n} $ we have to find the radius of convergence of the power series. If we use the fact that radius of convergence is limit of the the sequence $ \frac {a_n}{a_{n+1}} $ as n tends to $ \infty $ I am getting the radius of convergence to be = $\frac{1}{2}$
could someone please guide me if I am right or wrong and consider posting a valid justification in each of the above scenario !

Comment: $$\sum (1+n+2^{n}) x^{n}\sim \sum (2^{n}) x^{n}=\sum (2x) ^{n}\to |x|<\frac 12$$ you are right

Comment: thanks ! for the help @Khosrotash

Comment: See Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula in wikipedia. IF $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n/a_{n+1}=r\in \Bbb R\cup \{\infty\}$ exists THEN $r$ is the radius of convergence of $\sum_n a_nx^n,$ as you said. But every power series has a radius of convergence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2=\sqrt[n]{2^n} \leq \sqrt[n]{1+n+2^n} \leq \sqrt[n]{2^n+2^n+2^n}=2\sqrt[n]{3} \to 2$$